# how i can store image from UWP application and get on android app ? (using sqlite or something else)

Tags: android, sqlite, uwp

I am getting images from a webcam and want to store it in a database, and user get this stored image on his/her android app.
please tell me a way to do that. Thanks

Comment: Don't you have a server to do this?

Comment: actually its my university project, i can't buy a server for that :/

Comment: Suppose you have a database now saved with pictures in a uwp device, how you want to copy it to android device? Why you need this feature? Not all the server are paid. Why not save it on one drive or any other cloud free storages?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's not a good way to consider using [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) to save images directly, the recommended way is to save the image paths. Since you don't have a server to saving images for different platforms, I recommend you to use cloud storages to save the image sources such as [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/) and [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-introduction). OneDrive for personal may be free.

If you are choosing to use OneDrive, you can use the [Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) APIs to access the images in OneDrive, and which is supported in UWP as well as the Andriod platform.  For Graph samples and SDK for UWP and Andriod please reference [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks).